# Chartjs plugin annotation timestamp

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs, chartjs-plugin-annotation

I am using Chart.Js "2.8.0" and chartjs-plugin-annotation "0.5.7" to display boxes based on timestamp intervals

I am trying to show something like this: [image]
based on timstamp intervals, but cannot find something from their docs.

The result is...:
[image]

code examples:

```
annotations.push({
    type: 'box',
    id: `status-${index}`,
    xScaleID: `x-axis-${index}`,
    yScaleID: `y-axis-${index}`,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(188, 170, 164, 0.2)',
    borderWidth: 0,
    xMin: data.linkedTime, // timestamp
    xMax: data.unlinkedTime, // timestamp - can be null(till present)
    label: {
        enabled: true,
        fontSize: 12,
        drawTime: 'afterDraw',
        content: data.name,
        xAdjust: 0,
        yAdjust: 0,
        position: 'top'
    }
});
```

chart xaxis (using dayjs `let labels = items.map(({ time }) => this.$dayjs.unix(time));`):

```
xAxes: [
    {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            unit: 'day',
            unitStepSize: 1,
            displayFormats: {
                day: 'MMM DD'
            }
        }
    }
],
```

My guess is that i should format the xMin/xMAx values accordingly to xaxis (daysjs stuff), tried something(`'Oct 31'` or `this.$dayjs.unix(timestamp)`) but it doesn't work... i guess i am missing something

Comment: AFAIK the data for time axes are managed as epoch (I don't recall in CHART.2.8.0 if there was any difference). Can you provide the data or to create a codepen in order to investigate a little  bit more? off-topic: the box annotation is configured to have the label but in version 0.5.7 the box label wasn't implemented.

Comment: I have created a codepen (using luxon): https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/eYKZmOY I set xMin and xMax with the date format. It sounds working.

Comment: Thanks @user2057925, fixed with:  `dayjs.unix(timestamp).valueOf()` 

The only downside is the label that is not implemented on this version of the plugin....
trying to find another way...

Answer (score 1):

Chart.js uses timestamps defined as **milliseconds** since the epoch. [Source](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html)

Use `.valueOf()` to get timestamp in milliseconds from dayjs. [Source](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/unix-timestamp-milliseconds)

```
xMin: dayjs(...).valueOf(),
xMax: dayjs(...).valueOf(),
```

Comment: ha...  it seems this was the issue,

yeap works now, 
thanks